# Como funciona o controle de versionamento de Apps da App Store?

Tags: app, versionamento, appstore

Estou precisando publicar uma nova versão (1.0.1.10) de um aplicativo que está publicado com a versão 1.0.1.

Ao tentar publicar estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ERROR ITMS-90060: "this bundle is invalid. The value for key
>   CFBundleShortVersionString '1.0.1.10' in the info.plist file must be a
>   period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."

Só é possível publicar com três casas decimais? 
Consegui fazer este procedimento na Google Play sem problemas.

Comment: Você usa `CocoaPods` ou algo do gênero?

Answer (score 1):

O formato que está utilizando, `1.0.1.10`, o 10 seria a nomenclatura do build que está fazendo, certo?

Pesquisando e conforme documentação da Apple sobre versionamento, é obrigatório o padrão de para versões o `1.2.3`, que seria algo assim:

1. Versão Maior(MAJOR): quando fizer mudanças incompatíveis na API,
2. Versão Menor(MINOR): quando adicionar funcionalidades mantendo compatibilidade, e
3. Versão  de Correção(PATCH): quando corrigir falhas mantendo compatibilidade.

<sub>Fonte: [semver.org](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/)</sub>

> **Version Number (required)**
>   The version number of the app you’re adding. This is the version number that will display on the App Store
>   for customers. Numbering should follow typical software versioning
>   conventions (for example, 1.0 , 1.0.1 , 1.1 ). When you create a new
>   app or platform the version number will always default to 1.0, but
>   this can be changed before you submit the app for review. Important:
>   Make sure this App Store version number matches the version number set
>   in the bundle. If these don’t match, upload errors for later updates
>   might occur.

<sub>Fonte: [Apple - Platform Version Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW3)</sub>

---

Se quiser saber mais sobre Versionamento Semântico, sugiro a leitura do site [semver.org](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/).

Answer (score 0):

Na mensagem de erro que recebeu, lê-se:

> [...] file must be a period-separated list of at most three
>   non-negative integers.

No ano passado a Apple publicou que todas as versões deveriam ser declaradas no seguinte formato:

`%d.%d.%d`

---

> A numeração deve seguir a convenção de versionamento típica dos
>   softwares (por exemplo, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1)

Fonte: [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW3) (em tradução livre)